# How to set a different unselected image and text color on UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I'd like to set different colors for a `UITabBarItem`'s title text and image in the unselected state.

For the selected state, I can accomplish this like so:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor purpleColor]]; // image color
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor orangeColor] } forState:UIControlStateSelected]; // text color
```

For the unselected state, I'm attempting the following:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setUnselectedItemTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]]; // image color
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor] } forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // text color
```

But for some reason, the `unselectedItemTintColor` setting overrides whatever I try and set for the `titleTextAttributes` – so in the snippet above, both the text and image would appear blue.

I've also tried changing the `titleTextAttributes` directly on the `UITabBarItem` after I've created it (instead of using `appearance`), but again this seems to have no effect.

How can I achieve different unselected colors? Is it possible?

Comment: This certainly looks like a bug. Options could be 1) use images only, or 2) use custom views for the tab bar items, or 3) custom tab bar controller?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this shortly after posting. It turns out that while setting the `unselectedItemTintColor` using `UIAppearance` overrides the `titleTextAttributes` for the item, everything works correctly if you set the `unselectedItemTintColor` directly on the tab bar itself.

So instead of

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setUnselectedItemTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

just do

```
[self.myTabBarInstance setUnselectedItemTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```